# why is Laravel Sail docker not running on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, laravel-sail

I downloaded docker for windows, installed it and it works fine,
I Created a new Laravel Project and installed Sails and it installed properly,

but when I run the sails up command (sails as an alias), then go to the browser and enter localhost, it takes me to and ubuntu page and not the Laravel home page, if I use Laravel.test, i get the error page of not found.

how can i solve this.

```
                                                   .[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmBIY.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYH2a.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to edit your `APP_PORT` in your `.env` file like this:

```
APP_PORT=3001 // or any number port you like
```

After that you can re-run your sail command:

```
sail up
```

Now, you should be able to access your site in `localhost:3001`.

The reason why your `sail up` command failed may be because your `PORT` number `80` already taken from some other software like `nginx` or `apache`

Comment: try to change your config to ```'${APP_PORT:-89}:80' ```